# How to write a generic interface with mandatory properties, and any possible property from T?

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say i have an interface/type like that:

```
export interface I_Employee {  
    id:string|number
    availableShifts: Array<string|number > | null;
    unAvailableShifts: Array<string|number > | null
    desiredNumShifts?: number | null
    minNumShifts?: number | null
    maxNumShifts?: number | null
}
```

But, i would like the implementing employee object to have any other property that exists in a type "T". Would look something like this:

```
export interface I_Employee<T> {
    [any key in T...]:T[some key...]//This is just "pseudo code".
    id:string|number
    availableShifts: Array<string|number > | null;
    unAvailableShifts: Array<string|number > | null
    desiredNumShifts?: number | null
    minNumShifts?: number | null
    maxNumShifts?: number | null
}
```

Of course i could just do *[index:string]:any*, instead of generics, but then Typescript does not recognize the properties, in some parts of my code. I have functions that receive certain objects and **mutate** them, therefore i need to be able to somehow make this generic.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with interface, but you can do with type:

```js
interface I_Employee {  
    id:string|number
    availableShifts: Array<string|number > | null;
    unAvailableShifts: Array<string|number > | null
    desiredNumShifts?: number | null
    minNumShifts?: number | null
    maxNumShifts?: number | null
}

type SuperEmployee<T> = I_Employee & T;
type SuperEmployee2<T> = I_Employee & {[P in keyof T]: T[P]};

const employee: SuperEmployee<{salary: number}> = {
  id: 1,
  availableShifts: [],
  unAvailableShifts: [],
  salary: 1000,
}

const employee2: SuperEmployee2<{salary: number}> = {
  id: 1,
  availableShifts: [],
  unAvailableShifts: [],
  salary: 2000,
}
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly it. Thank you!